# MikTeX suddenly stopped compiling

Tags: errors

PDFlatex suddenly stopped generating the PDF and started returning a bunch of errors.

```
C:\fithesis2.cls:103: Font \filogo=fi-logo at 113.81102pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. [\font\filogo fi-logo at 40mm ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty:149: Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option. [...ry to proceed from here, type x to quit.}]
C:/diploma-thesis.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel. [\usepackage]
```

Don't know what happened but it's not a syntax error in the document as far as I can tell.

All the packages worked fine previously - could a package be uninstalled without me knowing?

I need to troubleshoot this issue - tell me what information I should provide and I will paste it in the topic.

preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{fithesis2} 
\usepackage{babel} % package for multilingual support
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} % Windows OS encoding 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}


\lstset{
showstringspaces=false,
extendedchars=true,
frameround=fttt,
frame=single,
upquote=true,
breaklines=true
}
```

my bibliography database stopped working correctly for some reason, don't know why or how to fix it yet

```
C:\diploma-thesis.aux:93: Undefined control sequence. [\bibcite{citation}{24}]
```

Even an almost empty document like this wont compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{fithesis2} 


\begin{document}
testing text
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's your preamble?

Comment: Added preamble to question.

Comment: You have probably introduced a new package that also loads babel with another option and it is complaining about that.

Comment: tried removing one or both babels but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Removing everything except fithesis2 from preamble also does not help

Comment: Ah also delete the `.aux` file then.

Comment: Deleted .aux , removed preamble but still the same error.

Comment: Everything was compiling fine, then copied a few chapters from Word and this happened. Removed new text but it did not help, neither did restarting the pc.

Comment: It may have to do with my bibliography database not loading correctly, as this causes so many errors the build process is terminated. Will investigate

Comment: If a new, fresh document works (like `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[slovak]{babel} \begin{document} \section{One} \end{document}`), then there's something specific to your thesis document that's gone wrong. Maybe an accent or other unprintable character got pasted in from Word.

Comment: You also have two different `fontenc` lines. Not sure which one takes priority, but probably only should be one.

Comment: It can't find the `fi-logo` font. I assume this is a local font. Do you have it? Have you moved it? Has MiKTeX lost track of it?

Comment: A fresh document compiles fine - there are still a few errors but not enough to terminate pdflatex. My document has too many bibliography errors so the compilation terminates - don't know how my bib database got broken however :( Don't know how to fix it

Comment: Restore a known-good backup and look for differences?

Comment: Rewrote whole document with different document from older copy of directory and still does not compile, but the older document is compiling in its original directory. Could other files (except main text file} have gotten corrupted somehow?

Comment: Even a small document (updated in question} won't generate a pdf. Something is wrong with the system :/

Comment: The first error means that miktex couldn't create the tfm. Is the fi-logo.mf in a place where miktex can find it?

Comment: Here's a online diff of two files - left one compiles, right one does not. https://www.diffchecker.com/9akxike7

Comment: Show the log-file (of a compilation with pdflatex (pdf output!)) of the file that compiles. Btw: Are you really storing your document in the root of C:?

Comment: Removed \figure{SWOT analysis} from the tex file and now it compiles. Bloody hell, how could \figure have caused this ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed

```
\figure{SWOT analysis}
```

from the document and everything compiles fine now. Don't understand how figure could have caused it, still need to find a way how use it somehow to number images :/

Comment: figure is an environment not a command. But your answer contradicts your claim that "Even an almost empty document like this wont compile:". Are you sure that your document compiles now *without errors*? Only because you get a pdf doesn't mean that your code/system is sane.

Comment: You're right - I am still getting errors but at least I am getting some form of pdf output. I tried compiling the document without a preamble (that did not help) and also tried compiling a different (almost empty) document. The almost empty document did not compile in SublimeText but after closing and reopening the text editor it generated a pdf once. I suspect that when I tried to compile the broken (figure) document the compiler got stuck in the middle and could not execute the second file.

Comment: It is not a good idea to ignore errors: The next one can be fatal again and as you saw in this case it is difficult to debug a problem when a lot of "old" errors interfere.